# Filter data in pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor `X` like `[0.1, 0.5, -1.0, 0, 1.2, 0]`, and I want to implement a function called `filter_positive()`, it can filter the positive data into a new tensor and return the index of the original tensor. For example:

```
new_tensor, index = filter_positive(X)

new_tensor = [0.1, 0.5, 1.2]
index = [0, 1, 4]
```

How can I implement this function most efficiently in pytorch?

Answer (score 28):

Take a look at `torch.nonzero` which is roughly equivalent to `np.where`. It translates a binary mask to indices:

```py
>>> X = torch.tensor([0.1, 0.5, -1.0, 0, 1.2, 0])
>>> mask = X >= 0
>>> mask
tensor([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=torch.uint8)

>>> indices = torch.nonzero(mask)
>>> indices
tensor([[0],
        [1],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5]])

>>> X[indices]
tensor([[0.1000],
        [0.5000],
        [0.0000],
        [1.2000],
        [0.0000]])
```

A solution would then be to write:

```py
mask = X >= 0
new_tensor = X[mask]
indices = torch.nonzero(mask)
```

Answer (score 8):

If the index is not necessary, you could just do:

```py
X = X[X > 0]
```