# How to apply torch.topk only on non-zero elements of a tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to apply the function `torch.topk`, but only on the non-zero elements of the tensor (i.e, not to count zero elements in the counting process).

Currently I do this:

```
torch.topk(tensor.view(-1), k)
```

But this also considers the zero elements in variable tensor and returns the top largest among them. What should I do to get the topk among non-zero elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# get the top k values in a tensor excluding zeros
top_vals = torch.topk(tensor.view(-1), k)[0]
mask = top_vals != 0
values = top_vals[mask]
print(values)

# Get Indices of Top K Values
indices = torch.nonzero(mask)
print(indices)
```

credits: [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570043/filter-data-in-pytorch-tensor)